# Instantiate a Date object, given time as a string and a timezone?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a PST time in String format, I need to convert this to a String in system time.

`moment.js` isn't working for me right now since `moment.tz("1970-8-31 1:15", "America/Los_Angeles");` throws a `TypeError: _moment.default.tz is not a function` error.

Comment: You need moment-timezone, not moment: https://momentjs.com/timezone/

Comment: I installed moment-timezone as well, same error

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
const moment = require('moment-timezone');

var june = moment("1970-8-31 1:15");

console.log(june.tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z'));

// or

console.log(moment(june).tz('America/Los_Angeles').format('ha z'))
```

Comment: Doing that preceded by `Vue.use(VueMoment, { moment, });` gives me a `Module not found: 'moment-timezone'` error

Comment: Without the `Vue.use(VueMoment, { moment, });`, it converts the `"1970-8-31 1:15"` in system time to Los Angeles time (ie, when system time is EST, three hours after PST, it logs 4am EDT)